# Why does .size() not work on vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to learn sorting algorithms. I'm trying to set up the test vector which would be sorted by the algorithms - but nothing is working. The first algorithm I'm trying to learn is insertion sort. Have a look at my code and then I'll tell u my error messages:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int>);

int main(){
    std::vector<int> test[10];
    test.push_back(5);
    test.push_back(9);
    test.push_back(1);
    test.push_back(10);
    test.push_back(3);
    test.push_back(7);
    test.push_back(4);
    test.push_back(8);
    test.push_back(2);
    test.push_back(6);

    insertionSort(test);
}

 std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int> a[]){
     int i, j, k = 0;
     int n = a.size();
     for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
         j = i;
         k = a[i];
         while(j > 0 && a[j-1] > k){
              a[j] = a[j-1];
              j--;
         }
      a[j] = k;
      }
     return a;
 }
```

.size() doesn't work at all because:

> error: request for member 'size' in 'a', which is of pointer type 'std::vector*'

Also, for line 27 it says:

> error: cannot convert 'std::vector' to 'int' in assignment.

I have no idea what on Earth is going on.
If someone knows please drop an answer or better yet, link some resources or something.

Push_back wasn't working a second ago either - and yet now it somehow does - I have no idea what's happening.

At any rate, thank you for your help.

Comment: `std::vector<int> test[10];` is a c-array of vectors. C-arrays neither have `size()` nor `push_back()`.  I think you want a `std::vector<int> test;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Perhaps `test.reserve(10)`

Comment: "Push_back wasn't working a second ago either - and yet now it somehow does - I have no idea what's happening." make a clean build. Your calls to `push_back` must produce an error too

Comment: I think, vector works as an array and there is no need of defining it as array! otherwise it will assume `a`  as pointer and thus it can't call `size()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at your signature:

```
std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int> a[])
```

accepts an array of vectors rather than a vector. Try initializing your vector:

```
std::vector<int> test; // instead of std::vector<int> test[10];
```

And then tweak a signature:

```
std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int>& a){
```

Notice the usage of `&` in signature. That essentially means passing by reference. If you don't use it, the copy of the vector will be created and
sorted inside the function, while in the `main` function vector will remain unsorted.

Comment: Yeah this worked - thanks a lot my guy  I don't know why everyone downvoted my question I'll be honest - but thank you for helping me out.

Comment: `accepts an array of vectors rather than a vector.` Technically, it accepts a pointer to a vector.

Comment: @Wacy if you care, I downvoted this question because [it was not honest about the errors it produced](https://godbolt.org/z/Eo6qExKGG).  A question downvote signifies that the question is not clear or does not show research.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<int> test[10]` is an array of vectors, the vector class has a method for size, but an array doesnt...

If you are using c++17 or newer you can do:

```
auto n = std::size(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `std::vector<int> test[10];` test is an array of `vector<int>`s but not a vector.
Probably you will need to use `()` brackets `std::vector<int> test(10)`.

And in function, you don't need brackets at all.

`std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int> a)`

Answer (score 0):

- std::vector test[10] is incorrect. Test is already of type vector.
- Comments are in the code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int> );  //pass by reference is better though
    
    int main(){
        std::vector<int> test; // push_back() will allocate the size for you. 
        test.push_back(5);
        test.push_back(9);
        test.push_back(1);
        test.push_back(10);
        test.push_back(3);
        test.push_back(7);
        test.push_back(4);
        test.push_back(8);
        test.push_back(2);
        test.push_back(6);
    
        std::vector<int> result = insertionSort(test); 
        
        //for (int i; i<test.size; i++)
        for(auto x:result)  // cleaner
         std::cout << x << " " ;
         
        //std::cout <<  std::endl;
    }
    
     std::vector<int> insertionSort(std::vector<int> a){
         int i, j, k = 0;
         int n = a.size();
         for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
             j = i;
             k = a[i];
             while(j > 0 && a[j-1] > k){
                  a[j] = a[j-1];
                  j--;
             }
          a[j] = k;
          }
         return a;
     }
```